# What are -pi and -e when executing a command in perl

Tags: perl

When I want to replace a common word in many files I use perl from the command line in unix.
I want to know what are the -pi and -e when running it, and what happens if I don't put those.

Example: `perl -pi -e 's/design/dezine/g' *`

Comment: `perl -h`. `-i` makes inplace replacement

Comment: But don't stack `-p`, `-i` and `-e` as `-pie` because `-i` takes an argument and will see the `e` as its argument.

Comment: Here's a presentation I gave long ago called [A Field Guide to the Perl Command Line](https://speakerdeck.com/petdance/a-field-guide-to-the-perl-command-line) that has a quick overview with some examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all documented in [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) (obtained from `perldoc perlrun` and `man perlrun`).

- `-e` treat the rest of the argument (if any) or the next argument (otherwise) as Perl code to execute. Takes the place of a script name.

  ```
  $ perl -e'print "abc\n";'
  abc
  ```
- `-n` executes the script (or `-e` code) for each line of `ARGV`. The line will be present in `$_`.

  ```
  $ perl -MO=Deparse -ne'print uc($_);'
  LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
      print uc $_;
  }
  -e syntax OK
  ```

  ```
  $ echo abc | perl -ne'print uc($_);'
  ABC
  ```
- `-p` is like `-n`, except it also causes `$_` to be printed after the code is executed.

  ```
  $ perl -MO=Deparse -pe'print uc($_);'
  LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
      print uc $_;
  }
  continue {
      die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
  }
  -e syntax OK
  ```

  ```
  $ echo abc | perl -pe'$_ = uc($_);'
  ABC
  ```
- `-i` stands for "in-place". It "redirects" output back to the file `ARGV` is reading from.

  ```
  BEGIN { $^I = ""; }
  LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
      print uc $_;
  }
  continue {
      die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
  }
  -e syntax OK
  ```

  ```
  $ echo abc >file

  $ perl -i -pe'$_ = uc($_);' file

  $ cat file
  ABC
  ```